# How to keep MongoDB from wrapping integers with NumberInt

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a web app that posts a JSON request to a Node/Express server, which then inserts a new document into a local MongoDB database using the latest version of the [mongodb Node module](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/releases/tag/V2.2.9). When I view the documents using [MongoChef](http://3t.io/mongochef/), all integers are wrapped with `NumberInt(x)`.

```
"shirts" : {
    "adult-x-large" : NumberInt(2), 
    "youth-small" : NumberInt(1), 
    "adult-small" : NumberInt(1), 
    "adult-medium" : NumberInt(1)
}
```

I'm sure these wrappers are useful for certain applications, but I really don't want my JSON filled with them. Is there a way to disable this? I'm not sure if this is a MongoDB issue, a MongoChef issue, or something else entirely.

Comment: What is the problem if it is wrapped with NumberInt? Are you getting any issue because of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a display part in MongoChef. If you view the data in "TreeView", it should show the type as **Int32** with just numeric value.

As long as the datatye is **"Int32"**, it should be correct and as expected.

**MongoChef JSON View:-**

[image: MongoChef JSON View]

**MongoChef Tree View:-**

[image: MongoChef Tree View]

**RoboMongo Json View:-**

[image: RoboMongo Json View]

Comment: Thanks! I thought it might just be a MongoChef thing but wasn't sure. It makes it hard to copy the JSON and paste it into other systems that aren't expecting that notation. Maybe I'll look into RoboMongo again.